# Cannot connect to php-mpos with CgMiner: Pool 0 slow/down or URL or credentials invalid

Tags: mining-pools, cgminer, server, stratum, altcoin

I'm trying set up a local pool, using the php-mpos and the zetacoin-qt executable file, but for some reason, when I attempt to connect using cgminer, I get this error: Pool 0 slow/down or URL or credentials invalid, this happens even though I've created a worker in php-mpos, I am running all of this on a windows machine. My batch file running the program is this:

```
cgminer-nogpu.exe -o "stratum+tcp://localhost:9332" -O admin.user:password
```

My Zetacoin config is this:

```
rpcuser=username
rpcpassword=password
rpcport=9332
daemon=1
server=1
gen=1

block_nTime=1317972665
block_nNonce=2084524493
```

Comment: Can you give the solution that worked for you? i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, It turns out I didn't use stratum mining server properly, instead I used stratum alone.  There's an important distinction between the two.